# Upload 6GB DB file on PHPMyAdmin Xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to upload a database (db.mysql) file of 6 GB on phpmyadmin on xampp.

Can anyone give me idea how to do that. 
I know the way to maximize the size in php.ini, to upload database through cmd.
I need to know any other way.

Thanks

Comment: If it is a `.sql` file you should use mysql.exe over terminal/cmd

Comment: Yes It is .sql file, but how can I use mysql.exe, I am using xampp.

Comment: With xampp you also installed mysql as database. In your xampp-folder under `/mysql/bin` is your `mysql.exe` file. open a cmd and go to that folder. Then execute the following command `mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE_NAME < FILE.sql`. Replace the capital words with your corresponding data.